# Does Boot performance monitoring include BIOS time?

Tags: windows, boot, bios

In the Windows 10 Event Viewer, to know the exact time it took a computer to boot, should I add the Last BIOS Time to the events marked with ID 100?

Answer (score 3):

It cannot include it.

Windows has no idea about what the BIOS is doing for how long and when it started; Windows gets started only *afterwards*.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Task Manager** in the **Startup** tab, *Last BIOS time* is displayed.

Comment: I know that. I'm asking if the number in the Event Viewer includes the time taken by the BIOS to initialize the hardware or not.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure, you could test is by just timing it yourself with a stopwatch ^^